# Getting result basis on count of another SQL query

Tags: sql, count

I have a table with the following columns:

- bkng_date
- bkng_id (varchar)
- villa_id (varchar)

This query

```
select bkng_date,count(*) as cnt 
from tab_bkng_det 
group by bkng_date;
```

returns the no.of records for each date as count.

Now I need to find dates in the resultset of this query `where cnt = 2`.

I tried a couple of subqueries but I'm not getting the desired results.

Comment: Add `having count(*) = 2`.

Comment: adding having clause worked. Thanks a lot @GordonLinoff and Tomas Z

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, correct and safe solution is adding `having count(*) = 2` clause as Gordon said.

For completeness, if you were curious how to solve it using subqueries (you didn't provide your db vendor though it's very likely your vendor supports `having` clause), it would be:

```sql
select x.bkng_date, x.cnt from (
  select bkng_date,count(*) as cnt 
  from tab_bkng_det 
  group by bkng_date
) x
where x.cnt = 2
```

or

```sql
with x as (
  select bkng_date,count(*) as cnt 
  from tab_bkng_det 
  group by bkng_date
)
select * from x where cnt = 2
```

Comment: I am using mysql. and did try the first option however it did nto work.  will try having option. thanks a lot guys.  Will post back once i've tried. thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Best Option is to use the Having Clause as follows,

```
select bkng_date,count(*) as cnt 
from tab_bkng_det 
group by bkng_date
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks milind. Got the same input from gordon yday.  And it worked. Thanks Nyway :)